# how to put an time interval on random image change

Tags: javascript, image, random, embed, document.write

i want to put an interval ,so that it will generate each time a random link from this function:

```
function random_imglink(){
    var myimages=new Array()
    //specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
    myimages[1]="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/standalone.swf"
    myimages[2]="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/mobil.swf"
    myimages[3]="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/3b2.swf"

    var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)

    if (ry==0)
    ry=1
    document.write('<embed wmode="transparent" src="'+myimages[ry]+'" height="253" width="440"></embed>')
  }
  random_imglink()
```

but the problem is that after i integrate the timeout to a func like this

```
  random_imglink()
  setInterval( "random_imglink()", 2000 );
```

after 2 sec it shows just the embed object, i mean the only thing that displayed on the page is the embed object, thats all.. and after another 2 sec it doesn't change the object... all i want is to change just the link inside the embed object, so that it wont brake the page vision, please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not write the embed object in timeout but overwrite it there.

Add the embed object directly into your HTML:

```
<embed id="randomEmbed" ...other parameters...></embed>
```

Then in your timer function change the writing to something like this:

```
document.getElementById("randomEmbed").src = myimages[ry];
```